# How to grep and match the first occurrence of a line?

Tags: shell, grep

Given the following content:

```
title="Bar=1; Fizz=2; Foo_Bar=3;"
```

I'd like to match the first occurrence of `Bar` value which is `1`. Also I don't want to rely on soundings of the word (like double quote in the front), because the pattern could be in the middle of the line.

Here is my attempt:

```
$ grep -o -m1 'Bar=[ ./0-9a-zA-Z_-]\+' input.txt
Bar=1
Bar=3
```

I've used `-m`/`--max-count` which suppose to stop reading the file after num matches, but it didn't work. Why this option doesn't work as expected?

I could mix with `head -n1`, but I wondering if it is possible to achieve that with `grep`?

Answer (score 3):

Using perl based regex flavor in `gnu grep` you can use:

```
grep -oP '^(.(?!Bar=\d+))*Bar=\d+' <<< "Bar=1; Fizz=2; Foo_Bar=3;"
Bar=1
```

`(.(?!Bar=\d+))*` will match 0 or more of any characters that don't have `Bar=\d+` pattern thus making sure we match first `Bar=\d+`

If intent is to just print the value after `=` then use:

```
grep -oP '^(.(?!Bar=\d+))*Bar=\K\d+' <<< "Bar=1; Fizz=2; Foo_Bar=3;"
1
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` is *line*-oriented, so it apparently counts matches in terms of *lines* when using `-m`<sup>[1]</sup>
 - even if multiple matches are found on the line (and are output individually with `-o`).

While I wouldn't know to solve the problem with `grep` alone (except with *GNU* `grep`'s `-P` option - see [anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041193/45375)), `awk` can do it (in a *portable* manner):

```
$ awk -F'Bar=|;' '{ print $2 }' <<<"Bar=1; Fizz=2; Foo_Bar=3;"
1
```

<sup>Use `print "Bar=" $2`, if the field name should be included.

Also note that the `<<<` method of providing input via stdin (a so-called here-string) is specific to Bash, Ksh, Zsh; if POSIX compliance is a must, use `echo "..." | grep ...` instead.</sup>

---

<sup>[1] Options `-m` and `-o` are *not* part of the [`grep` POSIX spec.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), but both GNU and BSD/OSX `grep` support them and have chosen to implement the line-based logic.

This is consistent with the *standard* `-c` option, which counts "selected lines", i.e., the number of matching *lines*:

`grep -o -c 'Bar=[ ./0-9a-zA-Z_-]\+' <<<"Bar=1; Fizz=2; Foo_Bar=3;"` yields *1*.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

First use a grep to make the line start with Bar, and then get the Bar at the start of the line:

```
grep -o "Bar=.*" input.txt | grep -o -m1 "^Bar=[ ./0-9a-zA-Z_-]\+"
```

When you have a large file, you can optimize with

```
grep -o -m1 "Bar=.*" input.txt | grep -o -m1 "^Bar=[ ./0-9a-zA-Z_-]\+"
```

Comment: `grep -o -m1 'Bar=[ ./0-9a-zA-Z_-]\+' input.txt | head -n 1`, which the OP himself mentions as a possibility, is conceptually much simpler (and probably more efficient and faster, although that probably won't matter in practice). More importantly, however, the OP is looking to solve the problem with a _single_ `grep` call; I'm pretty sure by "[...] possible to achieve that with `grep`?" he did _not_ mean to imply that _multiple_ invocations of `grep` are an acceptable solution.

Comment: @mklement0 I agree for the most part. When OP comments here that he was indeed not looking for a (slow and complicated) double grep, I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -P` (assuming you are on gnu grep) and positive look ahead (`(?=.*Bar)`) to achieve that in grep:

```
echo "Bar=1; Fizz=2; Foo_Bar=3;" | grep -oP -m 1 'Bar=[ ./0-9a-zA-Z_-]+(?=.*Bar)'
```

Comment: While your answer is perhaps easier to grasp than @anubhava's, it has the distinct disadvantage of not finding matches on lines that contain `Bar=` only _once_.